# getting more informative log output in PHP on webhosting PDO

Tags: php, pdo, web-hosting

I have been developing complex platform, on which to build latter. I have reached the point when it works on mine lamp, but not when via webhosting. One of mine function designed to log the variables to the database during operation keeps sending just a petty

> **Fatal error**:   in **/home/.../asi/kluckaSpolocne.php** on line **51**

This points to the exception of execute statement:

```
throw new \PDOException($e->getMessage(), (int)$e->getCode());
```

the code in question:

```
//echo "\n Spolocne ";
    //require 'ochrana.php';
    // include 'databazaCitaj.php';
    $dbuzyvatel = "mine login";
    $dbheslo    = "mine password";
//$charset = 'utf8mb4';
    $opt        = [
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
                PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
            ];
    try {
        $databaza   = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mine_database", $dbuzyvatel, $dbheslo);
        $databaza->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch (\PDOException $e) {
     throw new \PDOException($e->getMessage(), (int)$e->getCode());
    }

# $preloz = $databaza->prepare('select ? from preklady where jazyk=?');


    $GLOBALS['nová']=false;
    $DlzkaVystupu=1;
    $IC=0;
    $Hesla=json_encode(array(1,1));
    $HlavnýÚčel=0;
    $Kolá=array(0);
    $Hlasenia['Premenna']=' ';
    $Hlasenia['Text']=' ';
    $Hlasenia['Cislo']=1;
    $Hlasenia['JS']='[0]';
    $Hlasenia['Kdo']=0;
    $Hlasenia['Vlastnosti']='[0]';
    //print_r($Hlasenia);


    /*$hlásenie=$databaza->prepare('insert into Hlásenia (Premenná, Text) 
    values (:Premenna, :Text)');//*/
    $hlásenie=$databaza->prepare('insert into Hlásenia (Premenná, Text, Cislo, JS, Kdo, Vlastnosti) 
    values (:Premenna, :Text, :Cislo, :JS, :Kdo, :Vlastnosti)');//*/
    $hlásenie->bindParam(':Premenna', $Hlasenia['Premenna']);
    $hlásenie->bindParam(':Text', $Hlasenia['Text']);
    $hlásenie->bindParam(':Cislo', $Hlasenia['Cislo']);
    $hlásenie->bindParam(':JS', $Hlasenia['JS']);
    $hlásenie->bindParam(':Kdo', $Hlasenia['Kdo']);
    $hlásenie->bindParam(':Vlastnosti', $Hlasenia['Vlastnosti']);//*/
    // print_r($hlásenie);
    try { $hlásenie->execute(); 
    } catch (\PDOException $e) {
            throw new \PDOException($e->getMessage(), (int)$e->getCode());
    }//*/
```

Any idea about how to get some useful info about what is wrong?

Comment: Do not use try ... throw.. catch for your queries. It is only useful for the connection.Other than that, it **should** give you the detailed error message. May be it's your  function designed to log the variables makes it this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's your "function designed to log the variables" is messing with the error message.

Make it this way:

```
set_exception_handler(function ($e)
{
    error_log($e);
    http_response_code(500);
    if (ini_get('display_errors')) {
        echo $e;
    } else {
        echo "<h1>500 Internal Server Error</h1>
              An internal server error has been occurred.<br>
              Please try again later.";
    }
});
```

It will catch every exception and log it into web-server's error log. 
It's part of a [complete error handling solution](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting#code) I wrote.